# Latin-1 and the unicode factory in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a Python 2.6 script that is gagging on special characters, encoded in Latin-1, that I am retrieving from a SQL Server database. I would like to print these characters, but I'm somewhat limited because I am using a library that calls the `unicode` factory, and I don't know how to make Python use a codec other than `ascii`.

The script is a simple tool to return lookup data from a database without having to execute the SQL directly in a SQL editor. I use the [PrettyTable](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/) 0.5 library to display the results.

The core of the script is this bit of code. The tuples I get from the cursor contain integer and string data, and no Unicode data. (I'd use `adodbapi` instead of `pyodbc`, which would get me Unicode, but `adodbapi` gives me other problems.)

```
x = pyodbc.connect(cxnstring)
r = x.cursor()
r.execute(sql)

t = PrettyTable(columns)
for rec in r:
    t.add_row(rec)
r.close()
x.close()

t.set_field_align("ID", 'r')
t.set_field_align("Name", 'l')
print t
```

But the `Name` column can contain characters that fall outside the ASCII range. I'll sometimes get an error message like this, in line 222 of `prettytable.pyc`, when it gets to the `t.add_row` call:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is line 222 in `prettytable.py`. It uses `unicode`, which is the source of my problems, and not just in this script, but in other Python scripts that I have written.

```
for i in range(0,len(row)):
    if len(unicode(row[i])) > self.widths[i]:   # This is line 222
        self.widths[i] = len(unicode(row[i]))
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. How can I make `unicode` work without hacking `prettytable.py` or any of the other libraries that I use? Is there even a way to do this?

EDIT: The error occurs not at the `print` statement, but at the `t.add_row` call.

EDIT: With Bastien Léonard's help, I came up with the following solution. It's not a panacea, but it works.

```
x = pyodbc.connect(cxnstring)
r = x.cursor()
r.execute(sql)

t = PrettyTable(columns)
for rec in r:
    urec = [s.decode('latin-1') if isinstance(s, str) else s for s in rec]
    t.add_row(urec)
r.close()
x.close()

t.set_field_align("ID", 'r')
t.set_field_align("Name", 'l')
print t.get_string().encode('latin-1')
```

I ended up having to decode on the way in and encode on the way out. All of this makes me hopeful that everybody ports their libraries to Python 3.x sooner than later!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this at the beginning of the module:

```
# coding: latin1
```

Or decode the string to Unicode yourself.

[Edit]

It's been a while since I played with Unicode, but hopefully this example will show how to convert from Latin1 to Unicode:

```
>>> s = u'ééé'.encode('latin1') # a string you may get from the database
>>> s.decode('latin1')
u'\xe9\xe9\xe9'
```

[Edit]

Documentation:
http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html
http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html

Comment: I've tried putting the coding at the top of my scripts, but that still doesn't work. I'll try the explicit decoding, but I hope there's a more general solution.

Comment: You probably don't want to set coding: latin1.  That changes the encoding of the script's source, not its data.

Comment: @Glenn: I suggested that because I thought that `print t` may print Latin1 raw strings.

Comment: My script doesn't have any string literals with non-ASCII characters. So that shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: @Bastien Léonard: The data that I get from the database is not Unicode. The character in question is 0xed.

I can't decode 0xed with the ascii codec. Is there a way to change the default coding just for this one function, so that `unicode` would work?

Comment: @Bastien Léonard: I got a combination that finally worked. I'll tack it to the end of my question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try to decode the latin1-encoded strings into unicode?

```
t.add_row((value.decode('latin1') for value in rec))
```

Comment: t.add_row([s.decode('latin-1') if isinstance(s, str) else s for s in rec])  # I think you meant this (or something like it).

Comment: Probably, depending on what that prettytable thingy need.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick peek at the source for PrettyTable, it appears that it works on unicode objects internally (see `_stringify_row`, `add_row` and `add_column`, for example). Since it doesn't know what encoding your input strings are using, it uses the default encoding, [usually ascii](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html).

Now ascii is a *subset* of latin-1, which means if you're converting from ascii to latin-1, you shouldn't have any problems. The reverse however, isn't true; not all latin-1 characters map to ascii characters. To demonstrate this:

```
>>> s = u'\xed\x31\x32\x33'
>>> print s
# FAILS: Python calls "s.decode('ascii')", but ascii codec can't decode '\xed'
>>> print s.decode('ascii')
# FAILS: Same as above
>>> print s.decode('latin-1')
í123
```

Explicitly converting the strings to unicode (like you eventually did) fixes things, and makes more sense, IMO -- you're more likely to know what charset your data is using, than the author of PrettyTable :). <s>BTW, you can omit the check for strings in your list comprehension by replacing `s.decode('latin-1')` with `unicode(s, 'latin-1')` since all objects can be coerced to strings</s>.

One last thing: don't forget to check the character set of your database and tables -- you don't want to assume 'latin-1' in code, when the data is actually being stored as something else ('utf-8'?) in the database. In MySQL, you can use the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` command to find out what character set a table is using, and `SHOW CREATE DATABASE <db_name>` to do the same for a database.

Comment: If it's using Unicode objects internally, there should be a way to get Unicode objects back and avoid pointlessly converting them back and forth.  As long as you always use Unicode objects you avoid most of this mess (that's how Python 3 always works).

Comment: I believe it does: "get_string".

Comment: @elo80ka, the data really is stored as Latin-1. I verified that before writing the script. Also (in Python 2.6 at least), ints cannot be coerced using `unicode(int_value, 'latin-1')`, even though `unicode(int_value)` works.

@Glenn Maynard, printing the results involves a decode, explicitly defined or not. I had to use `t.get_string().encode('latin-1')`

Yeah, I'm looking forward to py3k's widespread adoption, so that all strings are Unicode. It would save a lot of hassle.

Comment: @eksortso: you're right...character sets don't really make sense for numbers anyway.