# Python Source Code encodings does not work

Tags: python, string, encoding

On my Paspberry I run a Python script under Python 2.7.

I want to declare some string literals as Latin-1, not as UTF-8.

Therefore I added the statement

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

at start of my file. But regardless of which coding I'm use the following code snippet always declares my string as UTF-8.

```
    s = 'äöü'
    print '%s %d' %(s, len(s))
    print '%x %x %x %x %x %x' % (ord(s[0]), ord(s[1]), ord(s[2]), ord(s[3]), ord(s[4]), ord(s[5]))
```

Shows me always:

```
äöü 6
c3 a4 c3 b6 c3 bc
```

What is the correct way to declare a string literal with Latin-1 coding, i.e. In my case I would expect a string with 3 characters: 0xe4, 0xf6, 0xfc?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you can use:

```
s.encode('latin-1');
```

for your problem.

Example:

```
>>> s = u'ééé'.encode('latin1') 
>>> s.decode('latin1')
u'\xe9\xe9\xe9'
```

[Source of the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155903/latin-1-and-the-unicode-factory-in-python).

Give me feedback if you can do it.

Comment: yes that works bot I loked for a simpler solution to specify some plain string literals.

Comment: How simpler? Be more specific, so I can help you, maybe.

Comment: OK, maybe I don't understand python's philosophy. In other (C-based) languages I declare char s[] = 'äöü'  and I get a string with exact 3 characters. Python seems to do some 'magic' around this; but maybe it's a feature I don't understand. But for which the coding comment at start of file is necessary than? It doesn't change anything regardless what I specify - utf-8 or latin-1.

Answer (score 0):

```
'\xe4\xf6\xfc'
```

is a byte string with the 3 bytes you specified.

As to why it's not encoding properly, that depends on how your editor is saving the file.  You might want to check that it's being saved using Latin-1 by looking at your source file with [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm).